# Django: Is it possible to attach media files (css, javascript etc) to a View-class?

Tags: css, django, templates, view, django-staticfiles

I can't fins any information on how to define css or javascript files in a view like:

class MyView(View):
   ....

class Media:
     css = { 'all' : 'mystyle.css' }

If you have a form you can do like:
class MyForm(ModelForm):
   ....

class Media:
     css = { 'all' : 'mystyle.css' }

And then in the template you can print the files like;
{{ form.media.css }}

I like that Syntax very much and I like to keep the View-specific css files in the app-directory.

Does anyone know if it's possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you should be able to set a variable with the css filename/location in your view, and if you pass that variable to the render/response you should be able to access it in your template.

Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups

example:

```
def my_view(request):
    stylesheet = {"css": "my_view.css"}
    return render(request, 'myapp/templatename.html', stylesheet,
                  content_type="application/xhtml+xml")
```

and them templatename.html would be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ stylesheet["css"] }}"  media="screen"/>
```